# How to change dynamic range of an RGB image?

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I have 16-bit raw image (12 effective bits). I convert it to rgb and now I want to change the dynamic range. I created 2 map functions. You can see them visualized below. As you can see the first function maps values 0-500 to 0-100 and the second one maps the rest values to 101-255.

[image]

Now I want to apply the map-functions on the rgb image. What I'm doing is iterating through each pixel, find appropriate function for each channel and apply it on the channel. For example, the pixel is RGB=[100 2000 4000]. On R channel I'll apply the first function since 100 is in 0-500 range. But, on G and B channels I'll apply the second function since their values are in 501-4095.

But, in doing this way I'm actually changing the actual color of the pixel since I apply different functions on the channels of the pixel.

Can you suggest how to do it or at least give me a direction or show some articles?

Comment: I believe that this is referred to as a [luminance or tone curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_(tonality)). My first thought is that it might be best to work in [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) or [L\*a\*b\*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) instead of RGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is a very straightforward imaging operation, frequently applied in image and video processing.  Sometimes it's (imprecisely) called a lookup table (LUT), even though it's not always implemented via an actual lookup table.  Examples of this are gamma adjustment or log encoding.

For instance, an example of this kind of encoding is sRGB, which is a gamma encoding from linear light.  You can read about it here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB.  You'll see that it has a nonlinear adjustment.

The name LUT implies a good way of doing it.  If you can make your image a uint8 or uint16 valued set, you can create a vector of desired output values for any input value.  The lookup table has the same number of elements as the possible range of the variable type.  If you were using a uint8, you'd have a lookup table of 256 values.  Then the lookup is easy, you just use the image value as an index into your LUT to get the resulting value.  That computational efficiency is why LUTS are so widely used.

In your case, since you're working in RGB space, it is acceptable to apply the curves in exactly the same way to each of the three color channels.  RGB space is nice for that reason.  However, for various reasons, sometimes different LUTs are implemented per-channel.

So if you had an image (we'll use one included in MATLAB and pretend it's 12 bit by scaling it):

```
someimage = uint16(imread('autumn.tif')).*16;
image(someimage.*16); % Need to multiply again to display 16 bit data scaled properly
```

[image: Original image]

For your LUT, you would implement this as:

```
lut = uint8([(0:500).*(1/5), (501:4095).*((255-101)/(4095-501)) + 79.5326]);
plot(lut);  %Take a look at the lut
```

[image: Plot of the LUT]

This makes the piecewise calculation you described in your question.

You could make a new image this way:

```
convertedimage = lut(double(someimage)+1);
image(convertedimage);
```

[image]

Note that because MATLAB indexes with doubles--one based--you need to cast properly and add one.  This doesn't slow things down as much as you may think; MATLAB is made to do this.  I've been using MATLAB for decades and this still looks odd to me.

This method lets you get fancy with the LUT creation (logs, exp, whatever) and it still runs very fast.

In your case, your LUT only needs 4096 elements since your input data is only 12 bits. You may want to be careful with the bounds, since it's possible a uint16 could have higher values.  One clean way to bound this is to use the `min` and `end` functions:

```
convertedimage = lut(min(double(someimage)+1, end));
```

Now, this has implemented your function, but perhaps you want a slightly different function.  For instance, a common function of this type is a simple gamma adjustment.  A gamma of 2.2 means that the incoming image values are scaled by taking them to the 1/2.2 power (if scaled between 0 and 1).  We can create such a LUT as follows:

```
lutgamma = uint8(256.*(((0:4095)./4095).^(1/2.2)));
plot(lutgamma);
```

[image: Plot of a gamma LUT]

Again, we apply the LUT with a simple indexing:

```
convertedimage = lutgamma(min(double(someimage)+1, end));
```

And we get the following image:

[image]

Using a smooth LUT will usually improve overall image quality.  A piecewise linear LUT will tend to cause the resulting image to have odd discontinuities in the shaded regions.

These are so common in many imaging systems that LUTs have file formats.  To see what I mean, look at this [LUT generator](http://www.arri.com/camera/alexa/tools/lut_generator/) from a major camera company.  LUTs are a big deal, and it looks like you're on the right track.

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1 - what is `79.5326` number? 2 - Even in this solution different functions will be applied on each channel. Assume rgbPxl= [50,2000, 3000]. The first function will be applied on red channel and second function will be applied on green and blue channels, isn't it? Thus, we'll change the actual color. Do I miss something in understanding?

Comment: am I right saying that even in your approach two different functions will be applied on each channel?

Comment: That constant `79.5326` is just the linear offset value for the second part of your piecewise linear function.  It's computed from `101 - 501*(255-101)/(4095 - 501)`.  The example shown applies the same LUT to every channel, which is what is needed in RGB space to preserve color.  If we want to apply a different function to each channel, we'd need to specifically index each color channel independently, like 'convertedimage(:,:,1) = lut(double(someimage(:,:,1))+1);' for the red channel, etc.

Comment: I understand that the same LUT is used for every channel. But, the was I see it is: first curve with a slope M1 is applied on one channel and a second curve with slope M2 is applied on 2 other channels. So,  that means that channels are not changed proportionally, right? It means that actual color is changed, didn't it? I'll appreciate an explanation if I didn't understand it correctly.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by "color".  Applying a contrast transformation necessarily changes the data in the image, but the apparent hue will be left intact.  RGB is an orthogonal intensity space, so all three elements are intensity values (not an angle as in HSV or HSL), so applying the same intensity function, even with a changing derivative, will result in a contrast function change only.  Shorter answer: it works to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to something that Photoshop calls *"Enhance Monochromatic Contrast"*, which is described [here](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/how-to-apply-the-auto-image-commands-as-adjustment-layers/) - look at *"Step 3: Try Out The Different Algorithms"*.

Basically, I think you find a **single** min from all the channels and a **single** max from across all 3 channels and apply the same scaling to all the channels, rather than doing each channel individually with its own min and max.

Alternatively, you can convert to *Lab* (Lightness plus `a` and `b`) mode and apply your function to the Lightness channel (without affecting the `a` and `b` channels which hold the colour information) then transform back to RGB, your colour unaffected.